# Building Covariance Matrix From Samples and not Features

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix

In most of the applications, I see that the covariance matrix is calculated on feature space,  by first applying normalization steps on $X$ then the covariance is calculated by $C = X^{T}X$ where $X \in R^{n, d}$; $n$ being the number of samples, and $d$ is the dimension of the feature space. This operation results a covariance matrix $C \in R^{d,d}$.

I was wondering what does a covariance matrix  $C'$ that is equal to $XX^{T}$ gives ($C'\in R^{n,n}$)? What would be its interpretation? And are there any use cases?

B.R.

p.s. Sorry for the bad title but don't know how to call it.

Comment: First, this is not the covariance matrix.  The covariance matrix is obtained by subtracting the column means from the columns of $X$ and then forming the cross product.  This makes sense because each feature is expressed in the same way with the same units of measurement.  Ordinarily, there are multiple features in each row and the meanings (and units of measurement) of those features may vary.  Consider, then, how it could even make sense to compute the *row* means, much less subtract these from the row values themselves.  (There *are* some special circumstances like this.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You are right, I forgot to mention about the normalization step. But assuming that we applied normalization : first unit normalization is applied then centering and then unit normalization again to $X$ . And finally, we get $normalizedX$. What would be the meaning of calculating the $normalizedXnormalizedX^{T}$ ?

Comment: Again, except in certain circumstances this is obviously meaningless.  At a minimum, then, such an operation would not be a general one.  The main application of which I am aware is as a form of standardizing rows for a Principal Components Analysis of a set of closely related factors, such as spectral intensities or chemical concentrations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and response.

Answer (score 0):

This matrix is called the Gram matrix and it is the matrix whose $(i, j)$ entry is the inner product of vectors $x_i$ and $x_j$ (if $X$ is the matrix whose $i$-th row is $x_i$).

If you want to normalize the row-vectors before taking inner products (by removing the means), you can consider it a covariance matrix as well. Why would you do this? Well, in many cases the columns of a matrix are equally as meaningful as the rows. Imagine you have a matrix whose rows correspond to Documents (like scientific publications or news articles) and whose columns correspond to Words (like "President", "biology", or "Twitter"). You could write a $1$ in the $(i, j)$ entry of the matrix if the $j$-th word appears in the $i$-th document, and a $0$ otherwise. Now you can imagine how determining the covariance of Documents could be useful (perhaps in document clustering with PCA) and how determining the covariance of Words could also be useful (perhaps in knowledge graph creation).

A more broad field of study in this direction could be called co-clustering. The idea is that

1. Documents are similar to one another if they contain the same word;
2. Words are similar to one another if they appear in the same document;
3. Documents are similar to one another if they contain *similar* words;
4. Words are similar to one another if they appear in *similar* documents;
5. And so on!